# get openlayers vectorTile features

Tags: openlayers

Found a solution to the below.  simply use the style property which exposes each feature.

```
this.vec_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: vectorTileSource,
    style: (feature: any, resolution: any) => {
        // access adn edit each feature here...
    }
});
```

Original Question:

How do I obtain and iterate over each feature in an openlayers vectorTile. the features returned in my json all have a different "status" key and I need to style them based on that key.  The api:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html

has a method forEachFeature() and getFeatures() but when I call either on the "source" I get undefined.

```
this.gisi_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({
      url : 'https://tiles.gisinventory.net/raster/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      wrapX : true
    })
});
let myLonLat = [-104.036667, 36.895];
let myLonLatMercator = ol.proj.fromLonLat(myLonLat);
// note that the target cannot be set here!
this.map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [this.gisi_layer],
    view: new ol.View({
    center: myLonLatMercator,
    zoom: 4
    })
});
// the source I need access to
let vectorTileSource = new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
    tilePixelRatio: 16,
    url: 'https://tiles.gisinventory.net/vector/layer_county_13/{z}/{x}/{y}.json'
});
this.vec_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: vectorTileSource,
    style: this.mapStyles.styleComplete
});

vectorTileSource.on('tileloadend', () => {
    this.setMapLoadingStatus('inactive');
});

this.map.addLayer(this.vec_layer);
```

The call to get source works fine:

```
let vectorSource = this.vec_layer.getSource();

console.log(vectorSource.getFeatures()); // undefined
```

I have spent two days trying to find out how people iterate over the features in a vector layer and none of the methods work.  I have inspected every object and don't see the methods exposed the documentation outlines.

Any help on techniques greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the Code you are using `ol.source.VectorTile` but the api link is for `ol.source.Vector`.  If you look at the documentation of `ol.source.VectorTile` there is no method called `getFeatures()` http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.VectorTile.html

Comment: Yes.  exactly.  I'm trying to get access to the source so I can call those methods.

Comment: You can use `getFeaturesInExtent()`